# Race condition in Django while using transaction

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Using Django, I got the following (minimal) model :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField


class MyModel(models.Model)
    files = JSONField(default=list)
```

In a view, I have the following code, in order to append data to the `files` field:

```
from django.db import transaction

def my_view(request):
    [...]
    with transaction.atomic():
        entry = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(id=some_id)
        entry.files += [some_value_a, some_value_b]
        entry.save()
    [...]
```

When performing requests one by one, the code is working fine.

However, **when performing several requests in parralel, some values are lost**. It seems to be a race condition, but since the append is performed within an atomic transaction block, it should not happen.

For exemple, if I perform the request 5 times in parralel, I end up with 8 values in the field (instead of 10), while having 5 `HTTP_200_OK` responses.

How to have a **trully atomic** block ?